# How to pass a Dataset Column into a VB Function?

Tags: vb.net, function, visual-studio-2008, dataset, microsoft-reporting

I have generated this report  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zgiu3glhsgb8wu/Stack.jpg) using MicrosoftReportViewer.
 
I was asked to show all Months of claims at the top of report.
I could Manage to get the name of first row "February" by following built in VB Expression 
        `MonthName(Month(First(Fields!ClaimSubmitDate.Value, "DataSet1_DataTable1")))`

But I need to show the rest of the months such as (January, March, and April) as well.
I understand the Logic that I need to write a visual basic function in CustomCode of the report and pass the Column "Claim Date " to it as array and loop through the values and if there is a month change get that month name and save it in an Array or vector of months and at the end pass all MonthArray data back to the textbox.
Since I've never programmed in visual basic and what I don't know is how to pass column of dataset table into a function??? And What would be the datatype of that column once it got passed??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the `DataTable` as parameter then loop on the specified `Column` then store the months on a `ComboBox` as the following:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables(0)
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ClaimDate" 'Column name
```

If you want pass a `DataTable` as `parameter` to loop on a specific `Column`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CheckMonths(DataSet1.Tables(0))
End Sub

Sub CheckMonths(ByRef dt As DataTable)
    For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ComboBox1.Text &= Row("") & vbTab
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am afraid you didn't look to the picture I put the link for.
I am generating a report using MicrosoftReportViewer tool so the user can print it later or export it as .pdf Not a from and I need to show the all months name at the header of that report that is inside my data table and furthermore the comboBox will not be available in MicrosoftReportViewer.